# Can צָוָה mean "gave charge" in Genesis?

Tags: hebrew, genesis, translation-philosophy

Most English translations say something like:

> And the LORD God **commanded** the man, saying, “Of every tree of the garden you are free to eat;

The Hebrew says:

> **ויצו** יהוה אלהים על־האדם לאמר מכל עץ־הגן אכל תאכל

It seems that **[וַיְצַו֙](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/6680.htm)** should be translated as "gave charge over" as in Adam was given responsibility to choose whatever he wanted to do. According to NAS Exhaustive Concordance, צָוָה means:

> Word Origin: a prim. root
>
> Definition:
>   **to lay charge (upon), give charge (to)**, command, order
>
> NASB Translationç
>   **appoint (1), appointed (4), appoints (1), charge (5), charged (17), charging (1)**, command (56), commanded (332), commander (1), commanding (18), commands (6), **commission (3), commissioned (4)**, **commit (1)**, gave a command (1), **gave them a charge (1)**, gave command (2), gave commandment (2), gave orders (2), give his charge (1), give you in commandment (1), **give you charge (1)**, give orders (3), given (1), given a command (1), given it an order (1), given command (1), given commandment (1), giving (1), instructed (1), issued a command (2), laid (1), laid down (1), **ordained (4)**, order (4), ordered (5), put (1), sent (1), set his in order (1), set your in order (2).

This would mean the charge to "not eat of" was actually a warning rather than a commandment.

YLT says:

> "And Jehovah God **layeth a charge on** the man, saying, 'Of every tree of the garden eating thou dost eat;"

And the NLT goes even further to say:

> But the LORD God **warned** him, "You may freely eat the fruit of every tree in the garden--

According to [Merriam-Webster's dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge), the verb charge means:

> to give a job or **responsibility** to (a person or group): **to make** (a person or group) **responsible** for something

This would mean Genesis 3:17 says:

> And to Adam He said, Because you have listened to the voice of your wife and have eaten from the tree concerning which **I put you in charge of**, saying, eat not from, cursed is the ground for your sake (benefit)
>
> וּלְאָדָ֣ם אָמַ֗ר כִּֽי־שָׁמַעְתָּ֮ לְקֹ֣ול אִשְׁתֶּךָ֒ וַתֹּ֙אכַל֙ מִן־הָעֵ֔ץ אֲשֶׁ֤ר צִוִּיתִ֙יךָ֙ לֵאמֹ֔ר לֹ֥א תֹאכַ֖ל מִמֶּ֑נּוּ אֲרוּרָ֤ה הָֽאֲדָמָה֙ בַּֽעֲבוּרֶ֔ךָ בְּעִצָּבֹון֙ תֹּֽאכֲלֶ֔נָּה כֹּ֖ל יְמֵ֥י חַיֶּֽיךָ

And Genesis 3:11 says:

> And He said, Who said to you that naked you [are]? From the tree, concerning which **I gave to you charge/responsibility** that you should not eat, have you thereof eaten?
>
> וַיֹּ֕אמֶר מִ֚י הִגִּ֣יד לְךָ֔ כִּ֥י עֵירֹ֖ם אָ֑תָּה הֲמִן־הָעֵ֗ץ אֲשֶׁ֧ר צִוִּיתִ֛יךָ לְבִלְתִּ֥י אֲכָל־מִמֶּ֖נּוּ אָכָֽלְתָּ

There are several instances where צָוָה cannot possibly mean "command" because no command is given. In Deuteronomy, the exact same form is used:

> "And he gave Joshua the son of Nun **a charge** (responsibility), and said, Be strong and of a good courage: for thou shalt bring the children of Israel into the land which I sware unto them: and I will be with thee." Deuteronomy 31:23
>
> **וַיְצַ֞ו** אֶת־יְהֹושֻׁ֣עַ בִּן־נ֗וּן וַיֹּאמֶר֮ חֲזַ֣ק וֶֽאֱמָץ֒ כִּ֣י אַתָּ֗ה תָּבִיא֙ אֶת־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל אֶל־הָאָ֖רֶץ אֲשֶׁר־נִשְׁבַּ֣עְתִּי לָהֶ֑ם וְאָנֹכִ֖י אֶֽהְיֶ֥ה עִמָּֽךְ

(Please see [Numbers 27:19-23](http://biblehub.com/text/numbers/27-19.htm), [Nehemiah 7:2](http://biblehub.com/text/nehemiah/7-2.htm), and [2 Samuel 6:21](http://biblehub.com/text/2_samuel/6-21.htm) for a few more examples)

Is it possible that צָוָה means "gave charge" in Genesis 2:16, 3:11, and 3:17?

Comment: This feels like a rather pointless goose chase. Even if you couch this fragment in the softest possible language, the inevitable conclusion from the context of the passage doesn't really change. It also seems to me you don't grasp the implications of the English "to charge" somebody with something. In no possible rendering (even if you used 'charged with' or 'warned') is Adam left as a free agent to define his own version of right and wrong in the case of eating/not eating from the tree.  What could possibly be said about this particular word that would change meaning of the passage to you?

Comment: @Caleb I don't believe Adam was a "free agent". I believe Adam did not "break a commandment from God", and therefore, did not sin. Does that help clarify why I'm asking?

Comment: Neither the YLT or NLT mean what you want them to mean. The YLT still means God commanded him. The NLT softens it to a warning for reasons I don't know, but neither mean that God gave charge to Adam.

Comment: @curiousdannii Why doesn't "layeth a charge on" mean "layeth a responsibility on", since that's what "charge" means? Charge originally meant "a material load", so it's also like saying "layeth a burden on". And that's also what צָוָה means in the other verses provided. The NLT says "warning", and that's *exactly* what I'm saying this was; a warning and not a command.

Comment: @anonymouswho I thought you thought the verse meant that God was giving a charge to Adam, ie, the delegating authority sense of charge.

Comment: @anonymouswho What do you think "warning" would mean in this context? It feels like you're trying to weasel out of something that is patently obvious from the context. You can use the word warning if you want but Adam still disobeyed God. A "warning no to eat something" vs. "a charge not to eat something", vs. "a command not to eat something" are not materially different and trying to give them different implications is clearly contradicted by the context. Any attempt to make Adam's actions not a sin given the immediate context of the passage would be fruitless.

Comment: @curiousdannii I do, but that is why I believe it's a warning. It's the difference between "Don't touch the fire" and "I command you not to touch the fire". God is saying "I give you authority/I put you in charge/I lay this burden on you to eat from every tree. But from the tree of knowledge, do not eat, because the day you do, you will die". That is a warning. It doesn't mean Adam has "freewill" and it doesn't mean Adam sinned. It just means that God warned him, but he didn't heed the warning;  just as God willed all along.

Comment: @anonymouswho It doesn't make sense to put a slash between "I give you authority" and "I lay this burden on you" as if they were different ways of saying the same thing. And there is much less difference between "Don't touch the fire" and "I command you not to touch the fire" than there is between either of those and "I give you authority".

Comment: @Caleb The immediate context is beyond the scope of this question. If you'd like to talk, we've been discussing this in the Upper Room at Christianity.SE. I don't see a single thing that indicates Adam sinned besides this one word.

Comment: @curiousdannii They *are* different ways of saying the same thing, namely *charge*. If you give someone authority, you've given them responsibility. When you make someone responsible of something, you lay that burden on them. There's a huge difference between "Don't touch the fire" and "I command you not to touch the fire". When you ignore a warning, then you just get whats coming to you. When you disobey a command, you get what's coming to you AND you get punished.

Comment: @anonymouswho "Don't touch the fire" is an imperative, and considered functionally much more similar to a command than a suggestion or warning. But I don't think either of us is going to convince the other.

Comment: You cite Merriam Webster's 2nd simple definition of _charge_, but ignore the full 2nd definition right below it: _(2a) to impose a task or responsibility on <charge him with the job of finding a new meeting place>; **(2b) to command, instruct, or exhort with authority** <I charge you not to go>; (2c) of a judge -- to give a charge to (a jury)_.

Comment: @Bʀɪᴀɴ Yes I did use the 2nd definition, because the first definition concerned the archaic use and electricity. The second definition was the only relevant one, and the 1st *relevant* definition of charge is "to impose a task or responsibility".  I also left examples that show צָוָה being used without any commanding instructions, so command cannot be the correct translation; nor can "charge" be used as a synonym for command in these verses.

Comment: @anonymouswho There are some contexts where specific instructions are not given and "charge" is the appropriate sense. That is why Hebrew dictionaries (not concordances, which you cannot use instead of dictionaries/lexicons) do list "charge" as one of the senses. But that only supports the traditional interpretation because Gen 2:16 does give the specific command which is being commanded.

Comment: @curiousdannii Genesis 2:16 says God charged Adam to "freely eat of every tree in the garden", and the "but" is added after the "charge" is given. For Genesis 3:17, the NIV, NASB, HCSB, ISV, and NET translate אֲשֶׁ֤ר as "about which" and YLT says "concerning which". The same word is used in 3:11, but none of the translations are consistent. "Concerning" and "about" mean "related to". So when God asks Adam if he ate from the tree *concerning which* He charged "do not eat", He is not saying "do not eat" was the charge, but that the tree was *one* of the trees which God gave Adam charge over.

Comment: @curiousdannii "And God said, Behold, **I have given you** every herb bearing seed, which is upon the face of all the earth, and **every tree, in the which is the fruit of a tree yielding seed**; to you it shall be for meat." Genesis 1:29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root צוה appears 221<sup>See comments below</sup> times in the OT in 109 different chapters. Roughly 70 percent are in the Pentateuch. The root appears in several different grammatical constructs, in both noun and verb forms and as part of idioms.

In all instances the meaning of the word is the same, "command" (as a noun or verb) or "commandment". The sense of the meaning in all cases is imperative.

In Genesis 2:16, ויצו is the Biblical "future past" tense (עתיד מהופך) used as transitive verb, with the preposition "on" (על) before the object "the man" (האדם).

The use of "appointed" or "charged" is justifiable as a translation in contexts where a Hebrew idiom uses the language of "command [someone] on [something]" (צו..על) or "[someone] is commanded on [something]" sounds odd to the English ear, or could confuse, as in Nehemiah 7:2, and 2 Samuel 6:21. These are probably the best choices for the English translation in these cases but they lose the clear sense of "command" that you get from the Hebrew.

In Genesis 2:16, the language is "commanded **on the man** saying...", **followed by the content of the command**, not "commanded the man **on the garden**", so the meaning is clear, God is giving an order, not making an appointment. The intended meaning becomes even more clear in the continuation, when the man transgresses.

It is a mistake to use the interpretive license that translators need to take when giving slightly different translations of a given word for a particular idiom, in order to re-read those different translations back into another, different, context. For example, in Numbers 27:19-23, the http://biblehub.com translation of יִשְׁמְע֔וּ, "they will listen to" (in the sense of "listen to and take to heart") in verse 20 is translated as "be obedient". That's a excellent, economic, figurative translation, but far from the literal sense. You can't then use "obedient" in other places where you find ישמעו unless the idiom is the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please let me make sure I understand you correctly. Are you saying that in rare instances, צָוָה *can* mean "appointed responsibility to" or "gave charge", but only if "command" does not make any sense within the context?

Comment: @anonymouswho [There is an inaccuracy in my post in that the actual Hebrew root of צו is actually צוה.] The meaning is "command" in all cases. The problem is in how to translate idioms such as "to command [someone] on [some institution]" that aren't clear in English when translated literally, and how to distinguish these from the idiom "command [someone] on [some subject], which often indicates a prohibition.  The sense of "command" remains, but it might not be possible to confer this in the term that is most appropriate for a translation. Your OP really made me think about this carefully.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. How would you interpret Nehemiah 7:2? I'm having trouble seeing how "command [someone] on [some subject]" can apply to this verse.

Comment: @anonymouswho Preserving the masoretic text word order, Nehemiah 7:2 reads "And I commanded Hanani, my brother, and Hananyah (the commander of the citadel)  on Jerusalem...". In polite English this means "I appointed my brother Hanani and the commander of the citadel, Hananyah, to be responsible for Jerusalem...". The Hebrew sounds a little more direct, like a military governor giving a command.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what "command [someone] **on** [something]" means. It seems Nehemiah 7:2 should say "And I appointed responsibility to Hanan and Hananyah over Jerusalem..". So Genesis 2:16 should say "And commanded, YHVH God, on the man" or "And appointed responsibility, YHVH God, over the man, saying...". Could you please clarify what "command on" means, and how it's different than "appointed responsibility over"?

Comment: @anonymouswho The word order of the Hebrew, in Nehemia 7:2 is "command [someone] on [something that needs a commander]" meaning "to make [someone] the commander of [something]". In Gen 2:16 it is "command on [someone] saying [do/don't something]" meaning "commanded [someone] regarding [something]. The difference is where "on" is in the sentence and to what it refers. Gen 2:16 could also have been written "commanded [someone] saying [something], without "on" (but with the Hebrew direct object particle "et", which is not translated, instead). The meaning would be the same but less forceful. HTH.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47837/discussion-between-anonymouswho-and-abu-munir-ibn-ibrahim).

Answer (score -2):

**Is it possible that צָוָה means "gave charge" in Genesis 2:16, 3:11, and 3:17?**

Well, of course, it's possible. After all, in the words of Francis Bacon, "*A man prefers to believe what he prefers to be true*"

If a person were to believe that "Adam did not break a commandment from God", then it would plainly be his/her preferred position, and we would be witness to him/her expending effort in gathering evidence and opinion to support it.

Here's the thing, though: a charge, or a commandment, or a warning, or an instruction to do, or not to do something, is merely **an expression of a sovereign's pleasure**. Parents are sovereign over their young children, teachers over pupils, employers over employees, governments over citizens, God over man, to name but a few examples of such sovereigns.

Now, when an expression of the sovereign's pleasure (a charge/commandment/warning/instruction/etc) is issued, then each member of the sovereign domain (home/classroom/workplace/community/creation/etc), must weigh up whether it is their pleasure to pursue the sovereign's pleasure or their own. It is pretty clear from the narrative that the Serpent, and Eve, and Adam were pursuing their own pleasure, contrary God's.

The very first use of the word *sin* in the KJV  ([Strong's H2403](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H2403&t=KJV)), occurs in a conversation between God and Cain. Here is my rendering of it:

[image]

"*if you do not do well, sin crouches at the door. Its desire is for you, and it will rule you by it.*"

So, what is sin's desire? The answer is as clear as crystal: that you pursue your own pleasure, contrary to the sovereign's.

This brought Cain undone, and before him, Eve and Adam.

### Conclusion

Adam sinned when he decided to act in accord with his own pleasure, contrary to God's, regardless of how God's pleasure was expressed.

So, choose any English word you like for צָוָה, it does nothing to diminish Adam's culpability.

Comment: Where does "by it you will be ruled" come from? You're re-vocalizing the *qal* to an (otherwise attested) *nifal*?

Comment: It literally says, "and you / rule she will / by it" or "by it she will rule you" or "by it you will be ruled" I painted the text so you could see the agreement.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think you're saying "Yes", but doing so in a way that still indicates Adam sinned. I have to disagree that a "warning" is automatically "an expression of a sovereign's pleasure". In the context of this story, I believe the "expression of sovereign pleasure" was revealed when God said "Let us make man in our image, after our **likeness** (1:26). Then it says "So God created man in His image (1:27)" Notice God prepares man in His image, but it doesn't say anything about His "likeness". After Adam eats, God says "Behold, the man has **become like** one of us (3:22)".

Comment: Concerning Cain, I think it's very relevant that the first use of "sin" is associated with him. After Cain sinned, God said "And now art thou cursed". After Adam ate, God said "cursed is **the ground** for **your sake**".

Comment: `@enegue` -- Nope, that's not what it says (literally or otherwise).